libtiff.so: undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'
I have a project in C++ using the Qt 6.6.1 library. My task is to link libraries statically. I took the Qt sources and compiled them:
sudo apt-get install build-essential ^libxcb.* libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libfontconfig1-dev

..Download source..
cd  /home/USER-NAME/qt_source/
./configure -platform linux-g++ -release -static -fontconfig -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -prefix /usr/lib/Qt6_st
sudo make
sudo make install

After that i am adding dependencies to the Cmake file by this guid, an error appears:
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable MY_PROJECT
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so: undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so: ошибка добавления символов: DSO missing from command line

My CmakeFile.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22.1)
project (MY_PROJECT VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set (CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -Wall -Wextra -O -MMD -lm -pthread -lstdc++ -latomic")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lz")

set (Qt6_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6")
set (Qt6Widgets_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6Widgets")
set (Qt6OpenGLWidgets_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6OpenGLWidgets")
set (Qt6Network_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6Network")
set (Qt6Multimedia_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6Multimedia")
set (Qt6BundledZLIB_DIR "/usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/cmake/Qt6BundledZLIB")

set (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX install)

link_directories (libs/)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64")

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

find_package (Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package (Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGLWidgets)
find_package (Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Network)
find_package (Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Multimedia)
find_package (Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS BundledZLIB)

include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include/QtWidgets")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include/QtOpenGLWidgets")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include/QtNetwork")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include/QtMultimedia")
include_directories ("/usr/lib/Qt6_st/include/QtBundledZLIB")

add_library (Qt6Widgets STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library (Qt6OpenGLWidgets STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library (Qt6Network STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library (Qt6Multimedia STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library (Qt6BundledZLIB STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties (Qt6Widgets PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/libQt6Widgets.a)
set_target_properties (Qt6OpenGLWidgets PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/libQt6OpenGLWidgets.a)
set_target_properties (Qt6Network PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/libQt6Network.a)
set_target_properties (Qt6Multimedia PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/libQt6Multimedia.a)
set_target_properties (Qt6BundledZLIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/Qt6_st/lib/libQt6BundledZLIB.a)

qt_add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME}
       ... here the sources
)

target_include_directories (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include/)

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::OpenGLWidgets)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Network)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Multimedia)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::BundledZLIB)


See What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

my guess would be that the Qt zlib version you're bringing in isn't compatible with the system libtiff library which is probably expecting to be linked to the system zlib library. Is there a reason you're specifying -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg when building Qt? That's generally only useful on platforms without built in versions of those libraries

@AlanBirtles You suggested the right idea. I recompiled without these flags. Problem still exists
